# Icecast AAC+ HTML5 Audio Stream on Chrome for Android - Strange Behaviour

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, audio, stream

I have an Icecast AAC+ (or AACP, AAC-HE) Live Audio Stream that I want to stream with HTML5 audio on a website. Playback on iOS Devices already works perfectly but I'm struggling with Android. I'm testing on a Samsung S3 with Android 4.4.3 and Chrome 39. Now to the strange part: When I press play and wait for about 1 minute playback starts. Can anyone explain why it takes so long for the stream to start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163951/how-to-play-live-aac-stream-on-android-with-html5-audio-element)), but I cannot get AAC+ live streams to play at all on Android, even if I wait several minutes.  Can you tell me how you managed to get Android to play the stream, even with the long delay?